# Comma-delimited text: read last two, add them, place them at end of each line

Tags: bash, csv

I have a file that looks like this:

```
GOES-15,167,170,+,3
GOES-14,150,146,-,4
GOES-13,100,100,-,0
GOES-WEST,-160,-170,-,10
```

I would like to read the last two elements of each line (for example **+** and **3** on the first line) and add them together side by side (+3) and put it at the end of the line with a comma delimit, so like this:

GOES-15,167,170,+,3,**+3**

Here is what I am trying:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

file=weather_sats.txt

while read line
do
    ADD=$(awk -F, '{print $4$5}')
    sed -i 's/$/,$ADD/' $file
done < $file

exit 0
```

This doesn't work, since I get "$ADD" at end of each line.

Comment: use **double-quotes** (") for your ```sed```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do what you wanted.

```
awk -F, '{print $0","$(NF-1)$NF}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pure `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS="," } {print $0, $4$5 }'
```

That produces the required output.